# Doctrine how to use ANY_VALUE mysql function

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Since mysql 5.7.5 group by have change

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

If I make this query

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
$qb->select('ANY_VALUE(d.id), d.nom, count(d.nom) as lignes');
$qb->groupBy('d.nom');   
$qb->orderBy('d.nom');
```

I have a error

Expression #1 of `SELECT` list is not in `GROUP BY` clause and contains nonaggregated column '`sepultures.d0_.id`' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

As explain in mysql doc, this problem can resolve with any_value like this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
$qb->select('ANY_VALUE(d.id), d.nom, count(d.nom) as lignes');
$qb->groupBy('d.nom');   
$qb->orderBy('d.nom');
```

But doctrine don't recognize this function

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected
>   known function, got 'ANY_VALUE'

How can I resolve it?

Comment: use min or max function? i.e. `min(d.id)`. The query will now be valid in all dialects of SQL.

Comment: It may be interesting to try adding the sql 'ANY_VALUE' function to doctrine2? Maybe interesting? [For the PHP crowd: adding custom functions to Doctrine 2 DQL](http://punkave.com/window/2012/07/24/for-the-php-crowd-adding-custom-functions-to-doctrine-2-dql). Also: [DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html).

Answer (score 7):

as vincent said, I must create a function :

```
<?PHP
//src/MyBundle/DoctrineExtensions/Utils/AnyValue.php

namespace DoctrineExtensions\Utils;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class AnyValue extends FunctionNode {

    public $value; // la valeur  passée en paramètre de la fction ANY_VALUE()

    public function parse( Parser $parser ) {
        $parser->match( Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER ); //identifie la fonction ANY_VALUE() de mysql
        $parser->match( Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS ); //parenthèse ouvrante
        $this->value = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match( Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS );////parenthèse fermante
    }

    public function getSql( SqlWalker $sqlWalker ) {
        return 'ANY_VALUE(' . $this->value->dispatch( $sqlWalker ) . ')';
    }
}
```

Declaration of doctrine extension class (with a key named ANY_VALUE) in the config.yml file:

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:        
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                connection: default
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        ANY_VALUE: DoctrineExtensions\Utils\AnyValue
```

the request:

```
//ANY_VALUE représente la clé contenue dans le fichier config.yml
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
$qb->select('ANY_VALUE(d.id), d.nom, count(d.nom) as lignes');
$qb->groupBy('d.nom');   
$qb->orderBy('d.nom')
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple way:

1- Install this php lib :

```
composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
```

2- In doctrine.yaml add this extra config:

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        ...
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
                DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                ....................................
```

For more details, official docs is available here :
https://packagist.org/packages/beberlei/doctrineextensions

Answer (score 1):

If doctrine does not recognise `any_value()` function, then you could execute the query as a raw sql statement:

```
$sql="select ANY_VALUE(d.id), d.nom, count(d.nom) as lignes from yourtable d group by d.nom"
$em->getConnection()->query( $sql ); //$em is the entity manager
...
```

I would not use a prepared statement unless you have any parameters (in the sample code you do not).

Comment: it doesn't work too, it's the same error : doctrine does not recognise :-(